# How Do I Test Shopware 6 plugin using PHPUnit

Tags: symfony, phpunit, shopware, shopware6

How do I carryout PHPUnit tests on a Shopware plugin.

Do I have to install PHPunit first within the plugin?

When I run `./vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration="custom/plugins/PluginToTestPHPUnit"` I get the message
"

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PHPUnit\TextUI\Application" not found in /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:104
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/bin/phpunit(120): include()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit on line 104
```

on the command line.

I am working with Shopware version 6.5.7.3